# SQL Alchemy ORM update row with obj?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a 5k row mysql table with 16 fields which looks like this

```
id a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o
```

I need to update each row

```
first_10_a = []
first_10_a = populate_a(10)

for selected_a in first_10_a:
 updated_row = {}
 updated_row = processing_magic(selected_a)

 #update row
 entry = db.query(myTable).filter_by(a=selected_a).first()

 entry.b = updated_row['b']
 entry.c = updated_row['c']
 ...

 # how to save the entry?
 # ?

session.commit()
```

I am using SqlAlchemy ORM so I have a class

```
class my_table(Base)
```

Is it possible to create a new object and then use that to update the row?

```
new_obj = my_table(update_row['a'],update_row['b'],update_row['c'],...)
#??? session.query(my_table).filter(a=selected_a).update(new_obj)
```

and if so how would it work with session.flush/commit/save?
(i.e. is it possible to mass commit outside the for loop, would that increase performance?)

I don't absolutely have to go that way so other suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: you _can_ do that, but: why doesn't `processing_magic` just change the attributes of the row object directly?  also yes you can just commit once outside the loop, that's fine.

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out how to recover each row and map it to an object.

Comment: how are you fetching the rows in the first place?  if you're using the ORM you should be getting back objects automatically, not dicts.

Comment: I was thinking `entity = db.query(myTable).filter_by(a=a).first()`
a is unique
but then I thought once I change values on the entity obj, how do I "save" this entity entry so it doesn't get overwritten by the next loop iteration?

Comment: i don't understand what you're asking.  also, if you're using `row[0]` then you're not querying the way you just wrote; can you post more of your code?

Comment: Yea sorry about that, I updated the code in my question. Hope that makes more sense.